# Switch cosmosdb from manual to autoscale

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, autoscaling, azure-rm-template, throughput

Is it possible to switch cosmosdb container from manual to autoscale using ARM templates?

I'm trying to achieve this with following arm , but I still get TU settings set to manual

```
{
  "name": "db/collection/container/default",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/throughputSettings",
  "apiVersion": "2020-03-01",
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "throughput": "4000",
      "autoscaleSettings": {
        "maxThroughput": "800000"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I think it's easier to [modify the setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-autoscale-throughput?tabs=api-async#enable-autoscale-on-existing-database-or-container) via portal. You must use arm template?

Comment: And I think arm template is used for deploying, so maybe [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-with-templates) could help you. BTW, you can create a cosmosdb and an autoscale container than choose to export the template to see the setting of this kind of instance.

Comment: I have multiregion deployments, some of them already deployed, some are upcomming all of the deployments are done via arm templates, except cosmodbcollections, but would like to switch to deploy them via arm too, if it is not so hard that not worth of spending time.

Comment: Thanks for response, and Mark has provided a nice answer :)

Comment: Be aware that if you go to 800,000 you can't go back to 4000. `Minimum throughput = Highest RU/s provisioned on the database / 100` https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#minimum-throughput-on-container

Comment: Further to @NotFound's point, going to 800,000 will also split your data into 80 or more shards, each that can be assigned 100-10,000 RUs. And if lots of people want to hit the same partition, none of the 790,000 RUs will help one iota; you'll have 429s. (If you are really bored and bloody minded, the 80 containers can be manually re-merged...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do this as this call is a POST on the Cosmos DB resource provider.

The only way to migrate from standard to autoscale throughput is to use the Azure Portal, PowerShell or Azure CLI. You can then modify your ARM templates and update the throughput amount by redeploying the template with the appropriate throughput json in the resources options.

Here is PS example for a container from standard to autoscale.

```
Invoke-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerThroughputMigration `
   -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
   -AccountName $accountName `
   -DatabaseName $databaseName `
   -Name $containerName `
   -ThroughputType Autoscale
```

More [PowerShell examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/powershell/sql/throughput?toc=/powershell/module/toc.json)

Here is cli example for a container from standard to autoscale

```
az cosmosdb sql container throughput migrate \
-a $accountName \
-g $resourceGroupName \
-d $databaseName \
-n $containerName \
-t 'autoscale'
```

More [CLI examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/cli/sql/throughput?toc=/cli/azure/toc.json)

If doing this for other database API's find the PS or CLI examples in the docs. There are examples for all database API's.

Answer (score 0):

It can not possible by updating to autoscale from manual. You have to migrate it using PowerShell script or you can done this manually on azure portal and update your ARM template.

It can be possible by following steps.

1. Update throughput to autoscale on azure portal.
   [Scale oprion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Cod.png)
2. Select Autoscale option save the details.
   [Select Autoscale option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ8Fy.png)
3. Update your ARM template as below.
   [ARM template changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRQpP.png)

Once you followed above steps you can update